# Help me recreate this text effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects

I have been trying to duplicate this effect on a different logo, and am having a lot of trouble getting the distortion to look right, especially around the edges. The logo I'm applying this effect to is pretty clean with hard edges. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

[[image: 90s AirBnb logo1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a bevel emboss and a stroke effect, using "Dissolve" as the blending modes.

An example

[image]

The settings

[image]Click to see larger

Comment: Thank you so much Billy! This is awesome. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but this is very helpful.